# Json Net $ref without id

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to use $ref to point to an attribute rather than an id in an object.

Specifically, in the below example, I want *AlternateAdress* to point to *city* attribute in *Address1*

```
 String str3 = "{
   'Name': 'Jon Smith',
   'Address1': { '$id': '1', 'City': 'New York', 'State': 'NY'},
   'AlternateAddress':{'$ref':'#/Address1/City'}}"; 

Person  stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(str3, settings);

Console.WriteLine(stuff.AlternateAddress);
```

The above code returns an error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'AlternateAddress', line 1, position 105.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Rextester.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: could you please share Person class

Comment: There is no functionality like that in Json.NET.  `"$ref"` objects can only refer to `"$id"` labeled objects that appeared previously in the JSON.

Comment: What final result do you expect?